Starting With Flask
I already downloaded anaconda in my laptop, and python practical has been done with jupyter notebook, I tried to activate flask with jupyter not book that give Warning message as "Use production WSGI server instead * Running on https://127.0.0.1:5000" press CTRL+C to quit. So now how to command in anaconda prompt to activate Flask?
I tried to activate Flask with Jupyter notebook, and now want Activate with command.

flask run or python3 app.py --host 127.0.0.1 --port 5000 something like this

Does this answer your question? How to run a flask application?
